# How to alter the time in vb to display a different date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently using this,

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").Value = Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy")
End Sub
```

in order to print the last save to my spreadsheet. What I would like to do however is have it print the date from 12 hours ago. Would this require a simple change to the code or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the DateAdd function:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").Value = DateAdd("h", -12, Now())
```

Comment: Does this answer work for you?  Please mark an answer as the accepted answer to the left.  If your question has not been answered please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what pnuts commented, you should subtract the hours from `Now`.
Try:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").Value = Format(Now - TimeValue("12:00"), "mm-dd-yyyy")
```